# MongoDB - What are the databases you can create inside the cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I just started figuring out mongoDB and tried to research this but Im still confused. So as I understand the cluster is the db for your project.

Then there are collections which are equal to tables in relational db's.
What I dont understand, inside the cluster you can create multiple databases, which then will include collections.
What are these databases (equal to) and when would I have multiple?
Im doing some tutorial where I have users and tracks. users is my collection and tracks is also a collection, both belonging to same db with name liftDB.
What would be the purpose to create more than one db inside that cluster?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: A database in MongoDB corresponds to a schema you may know from Oracle or others. System created databases are `admin`, `local` and `config`

Comment: Several databases are used mainly for organization of your collections, esp. in terms of privileges. You can grant `read`, `write`, `dbOwner` to databases which is easier than doing it for each collection.